# Migration from Windows ffmpeg 0.52 to linux ffmpeg 0.61 code error. How to fix it?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, ffmpeg

Previously I used ffmpeg on windows (0.52 build I found somewhere). Now I am porting to linux and to latest ffmpeg. So far I got 4 errors in 2 lines
On such simple line:

```
size = avpicture_get_size(pix_fmt, nWidth, nHeight);
```

I get:

```
  initializing argument 1 of ‘int avpicture_get_size(PixelFormat, int, int)’    C/C++ Problem
```

and

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘PixelFormat’      C/C++ Problem
```

And On such simple line

```
 avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)picture, picture_buf, pix_fmt, nWidth, nHeight);
```

I get:

```
 initializing argument 3 of ‘int avpicture_fill(AVPicture*, uint8_t*, PixelFormat, int, int)’       C/C++ Problem
```

and

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘PixelFormat’      C/C++ Problem
```

Code compiled and worked perfectly under Windows ffmpeg 0.52 but now gives such error on linux g++ on ffmpeg 0.6.1

How to fix such errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PixelFormat` is defined as an enum in pixfmt.h.  I think that the problem is that in C++, there is no implicit conversion from an `int` to an `enum`.  So, you need to explicitly convert the `int` to `PixelFormat`.  Try this:

```
size = avpicture_get_size(static_cast<PixelFormat>(pix_fmt), nWidth, nHeight);
```

or you could just make `pix_fmt` a `PixelFormat` instead of an int.

I don't know why this worked previously, because C++ does not allow `int` to `enum` conversion without a cast.  I think C does allow this though so maybe it was being compiled s C previously.

**Edit:** I just saw the API change from int to enum.  So that is why it compiled previously.

Answer (score 2):

Well the FFMPEG API has changed from old 0.52 to 0.6.1. You have to check the new API calls and adapt them. pix_fmt was an int, and is now a PixelFormat as your errors point out :)

In your case, the pixel format was an `int` in API calls in old FFMPEG and is now (0.6) an [enum PixelFormat](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h.html#60883d4958a60b91661e97027a85072a).

my2c

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answers, take a look at the old and new versions of APIs.

[Old](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.5/avcodec_8h.html#2884d6046e625b2b6eb3561ee87f8abc)

[New](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/avcodec_8h.html#54da074edd8339905bc90b75b1402d4a)